# Regular expression for parsing methods with arguments

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have this content for example:

```
<?php echo $this->translate("Any text", "Any text next", "base-key") ?> Next string bla bla 
string bla <?php echo $this->translate("SO Any text") ?> 
enter code heretext bla <?php echo $this->translate("and string", null, "article-key") ?>
```

So, I need a regular expression that match text between quotation marks in the first and third argument of method "translate".

The output might look something like this:

```
array (
  array (
    0 => Any text,
    1 => base-key
  ),
  array (
    0 => SO Any text,
    1 => null
  ),
  array (
    0 => and string,
    1 => article-key
  ),
)
```

I'm trying this expression:

```
/translate\(["\'](.*?)["\']/s
```

I just get the first argument string method "translate"

Comment: show us your code responsible for regex maching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got some success with this: `translate\(\"?(.*?)\"?(?:,\s?(?:\"?.*?\"?))?(?:,\s?\"?(.*?)\"?)?\)`. The way I wrote it, it will also capture 1st and 3rd arguments if they are not in quotes, you can undo that by removing the `?` in first and 3rd argument quotes and making the first argument optional - `translate\((?:\"(.*?)\")(?:,\s?(?:\"?.*?\"?))?(?:,\s?\"(.*?)\")?\)`

Can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/kG9eF3/1